# PHP response to ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

My PHP side sends reponse to ajax like that

```
$data = array(
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => $message
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
```

My ajax looks like that

```
$.ajax({
               url: formUrl,
               type: formMethod,
               dataType: "json",
               data: formData,
               success: function (data) {
                  //setup variables
                  var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data), cl, text;

                  //response conditional
                  switch (responseData.status) {
                  case 'error':
                     cl = 'error';
                     text = responseData.message;
                     break;
                  case 'success':
                     cl = 'success';
                     text = 'Qeydiyyat uğurla başa çatdı';
                     break;
                  }

                  $.notifyBar({
                     cls: cl,
                     html: text
                  });

               }
            });
```

Getting responseData is null error message. But (from firebug XHR) I see that php actually echoes result. What could be the reason?

Comment: declaring variables cl, text, responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data). I dunno what does jQuery.parseJSON.

Comment: You do not need parseJSON, because it will already be ready to be parsed, if you do `alert(data.status)` it will work (remove the parseJSON first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe jQuery is smart enough to parse the response JSON for you such that the `data` parameter passed to your callback has already been parsed. So you can just access `data.status`, etc. directly.